# 'module' object has no attribute 'qmainwindow'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, attributeerror

I am trying to create UI using PyQt4 on centos. But When ever I am trying to load QtGui.QMainWindow I am getting the error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(ui_file_path)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/__init__.py", line 160, inloadUiType
return (ui_globals[winfo["uiclass"]],getattr(Qtgui, winfo["baseclass"]))
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'qmainwindow'
```

This My Code,I am using python 2.7.9:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

ui_file_path = os.getcwd()+"/test.ui" # Enter file here.

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(ui_file_path)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `PyQt4`?seems that its `PyQt5`

Comment: Yes,i  m sure i m  using PyQt4. PyQt5 is not installed on my system

Comment: Works for me (on Windows), are you sure you're typing `QMainWindow` and not `qmainwindow`?

Comment: Yes i using same code shown above. Its working on windows but not on centos.

Comment: @abhijeetdeshpande. You need to **copy and paste** the full traceback. The output you posted has several typing mistakes which makes it useless for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04, using PyQt5, and python3. This could apply to PyQt4 as well, so why not give it a shot?

I found from https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html# the solution to be changing QtGui.QMainWindow to QtWidget.QMainWindow as they have changed. This also needed to be applied to QApplication as well, and the import of QtGui was not needed in the code (replaced with import ..., QtWidget).

I wish you luck in solving this issue.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, python3, and pyqt5, except it's QtWidgets instead of QtWidget

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I miss the point, but I don't understand why `MyApp` inherits from both `QtGui.QMainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow`.

Would something like this work for you?

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

ui_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test.ui") # Enter file here.

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        # Parent class init
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self) 
        # You may also write
        # super(MyApp, self).__init__()

        # Load UI
        uic.loadUi(ui_file_path, self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit**

There seems to be a case issue, here.

In my Python interpreter, I get this:

```
import os

os.PAth 
# This prints: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PAth'

os.path
# This works
```

In your case, you enter the correct case, but get an error with the attribute in an incorrect case in the error message:

```
class Myapp(QtGui.QMainWindow)
# AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'qmainwindow'
```

As if somewhere between the text editor and the interpreter, something had lowered the case of `QMainWindow`. I don't have any hypothesis regarding why this would happen, but it could be nested somewhere not obvious.

Can you reproduce in an interpreter? More explicitly, can you run a Python interpreter on the same machine and try this:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui
PyQt4.QtGui.QMainWindow
import os
os.PAth
```

and see what errors you get?

(Note: in your comment below, there's a case error in `QtGui.QMainWindow` (you wrote `QtGui.QMainWIndow`). I suppose you made it while writing the comment, not in the code.)

Comment: Inheriting from `Ui_MainWindow` means that the child widgets from the `ui` file will end up as attributes of `MyApp`. So the end result will be exactly equivalent to the code you've posted. The OPs example works fine for me, so I suspect the issue must lie elsewhere (probably the traceback would reveal precisely where).

Comment: Yes. As I was trying to understand his code, I realized it was close to mine but looked more complicated, so I suggested my way as a hint. Sometimes, when things get clearer, you just do things the way they should and the error disappears in the process. I agree about the traceback.

Comment: Hey Thank you for help but with you i getting this error

    Traceback(most recent call last):
       File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
           class Myapp(QtGui.QMainWIndow):
    AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'qmainwindow'

Comment: Yep, same error. I was just trying to simplify the problem, eventually leading you to a solution, but I didn't really dared to expect any direct resolution from it. I would have put that in a comment, rather than an answer, but I couldn't have fit the code excerpt.